# NodeJS -- cost of promise chains in recurssion

Tags: node.js

I am trying to implement a couple of state handler funcitons in my javascript code, in order to perform 2 different distinct actions in each state.  This is similar to a state design pattern of Java (https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state).

Conceptually, my program need to remain connected to an elasticsearch instance (or any other server for that matter), and then parse and POST some incoming data to el.   If there is no connection available to elasticsearch, my program would keep tring to connect to el endlessly with some retry period.

In a nutshell,

- When not connected, keep trying to connect
- When connected, start POSTing the data

The main run loop is calling itself recurssively,

```
function run(ctx) {
  logger.info("run: running...");
  // initially starts with disconnected state...
  return ctx.curState.run(ctx)
    .then(function(result) {
      if (result) ctx.curState = connectedSt;
      // else it remains in old state.
      return run(ctx);
    });
}
```

This is not a truly recursive fn in the sense that each invocation is calling itself in a tight loop.  But I suspect it ends up with many promises in the chain, and in the long run it will consume more n more memory and hence eventually hang.

1. Is my assumption / understanding right?  Or is it OK to write this kinda code?
2. If not, should I consider calling setImmediate / process.nextTick etc?
3. Or should I consider using TCO (Tail Cost Optimization), ofcourse I am yet to fully understand this concept.

Comment: Remember that `.then()` is guaranteed to be async so it's already doing something like `setImmediate()`.

Comment: What is the point of this loop?  Are you trying to eventually achieve some result and communicate that back to a caller?  Or are you just using this structure to loop over and over again?

Comment: Not really, I just want the program to run eternally, by remaining in  one state or the other.

Comment: Then, just stop chaining the promises.  Don't return it as Brad said.

Comment: Usually, one would use at least some sort of `setTimeout()` delay for a retry which kind of takes care of things (clears the stack, doesn't chain, etc...).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by returning a new promise (the result of the recursive call to `run()`), you effectively chain in another promise.

Neither `setImmediate()` nor `process.nextTick()` are going to solve this directly.

When you call `run()` again, simply don't `return` it and you should be fine.